# Angular rating readonly does not work on server

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have a rating component:

```
uib-rating(ng-init="average = xxxx", ng-model="average", max="5", readonly="true")
```

Since ng-model uses a local variable here, we consciously bind this component in one way. But the problem is with readonly attribute.

This works quite well on our local machine. But when we deploy it on server (linux astra), the stars are still active. What may cause this problem? (We use the same angular component versions on both server and local machines)

Comment: did you get it to work? I am having the same issues :(

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a little too late but for those who are looking for a solution, I had the same problem and the use of `data-readonly` instead of `readonly` solved the problem.